# Fast linear regression for binary outcomes

Tags: regression, logistic, optimization, least-squares, linear

I am currently implementing an algorithm which fits many univariate regression models for binary outcomes. Logistic regression is the natural approach. However, since there is no closed solution for the logistic regression problem, an iterative fitting algorithm such as Newton's method or the BFGS algorithm has to be employed which can be quite exhaustive compared to OLS regression.

Since my algorithm fits plenty of regression models (possibly millions of models), a fast as possible regression fit is desirable.
Thus, I am planning to implement simple linear regression models which have to be truncated at 0 and 1 for generating proper probability estimates.
My question is, if the corresponding least squares problem can be analytically solved or solved via an algorithm considerably faster than gradient-descent-like approaches used for logistic regression.

The desired regression model is of the form
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X = x] = \begin{cases}
\hat{f}(x) & 0 \leq \hat{f}(x) \leq 1 \\
0 & \hat{f}(x) < 0 \\
1 & \hat{f}(x) > 1
\end{cases},\;\;\;
\hat{f}(x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x.
$$
Thus, using least squares, the function to be optimized is given as
$$
L(\beta_0, \beta_1) = \sum_{(x,y):\ 0 \leq \hat{f}(x) \leq 1} \left(y - \hat{f}(x)\right)^2 + \sum_{(x,y):\ \hat{f}(x) < 0} y^2 + \sum_{(x,y):\ \hat{f}(x) > 1} (y-1)^2.
$$

Note that solving the regression problem $\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X = x] = \hat{f}(x)$ and ignoring the truncation at 0 and 1 (but applying it afterwards) does not have to lead to the same regression line which is illustrated in the plot below. The black line depicts the true function and the simulated data according to it. The red line is the fitted (ordinary) regression line which does not consider the 0-1 truncation in the fitting process.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? If you insist on using linear regression, why can't you just truncate the outputs? Notice that by penalizing the predictions you have no way of forcing it to be between 0 and 1 other than setting an extreme penalty that would make all the parameters equal to zero, so the regression line would be completely flat. Given this, what problem does your proposed model solve exactly?

Comment: Your apporach seems to be equicvalent to a generalized linear model with the link function $f(x) = x+0.5$ for $|x|<0.5$, $f(x)=0$ for $x<-0.5$, and $f(x)=1$ for $x>0.5$. I doubt that a model with this (not differentiable) link function converges faster than with a logistic function. The solution might not even be unique  because the exact location of all perdictor values outside the linear region have no effect. If you are looking for an analytically solvable probabalistic model for binary classification, have a look at linear discrimant analysis.

Comment: @Tim The optimization problem is given by the second equation in my question, i.e., finding a regression function $\hat{f}$ or equivalently parameters $\beta_0, \beta_1$ which minimize the loss $L$ in the second equation.
If I apply ordinary linear regression and truncate the outputs, I am not guaranteed to find the optimal solution in this space of "truncated" functions. I illustrated this in the updated version of my question where the true function is not recovered due to ignoring the truncation in the fitting process.

Comment: @cdalitz Viewing the model as a GLM is a nice idea. I thought there could be a fast alternative algorithm to obtain an optimal solution such as the PAVA algorithm for isotonic regression which also works with plateaus and kinks. Thank you for suggesting LDA. Definitely something I will consider.

Comment: I suspect you would do better with a quick update step, assuming each model is a small perturbation of the preceding one.  The OLS approximation could be pretty bad in comparison.  How are your millions of models related to one another and in what form are they presented to you (e.g., as a batch, sequentially, or something else)? The answer to your explicit question is "yes," with answers in thousands of posts here on CV: look up ones asking for regression formulas.

Comment: The models do not necessarily have to be related. The regression tasks are issued both sequentially and in parallel. Utilizing preceding models (if available) is something I thought of. Thanks for the advice. Are there really thousands of answers to the question if the truncated regression problem can be solved in a very fast way or did you refer to the unconstrained OLS problem?

Comment: I don't understand what might be constrained about your problem, because the constraints you have expressed appear to be completely artificial.  Why not ignore them?  If you really think there's any value in solving the constrained version, it's simple enough to do by first solving the unconstrained problem, checking whether any contraints are violated, imposing one such constraint (resulting in a simpler OLS model), solving that, and repeating once more if needed.